# SCS - to consume the last available message in kafka

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have a scenario where i want to consume the last message written to a kafka topic upon startup. For example if there is a "deal_config" topic with single partition, and there are three messages like `1 | 2 | 3`, upon startup, I want to consume only the message 3. If i set to `startOffset` to `latest` i can consume only the new messages. Ideally my consumer should read the offset of latest message in the partition and consume -1 of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality is not exposed by Spring Cloud Stream - you can use a `@KafkaListener` instead, with a `ConsumerSeekAware` listener [as discussed in the Spring Kafka Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#seek).

Comment: @GrayRussell. Can i use KafkaListener in a project which uses S-C-S Kafka binder. My need is to play with offset for fewtopics and all other consumers reads the latest offset always. So i used StreamListner and KafkaListener (with consumerseekaware) in the project which has spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka 1.2.1 and spring-kafka 1.2.1 (overrided)version. But the kafkaListner never works and no exception thrown. Messages are not consumed and my consumerseekaware methods are not invoked.

Comment: Yes; you can use both in the same application. Ask a new question showing code snippets of what's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

A wise man once said, read the manual ... http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Ditmars.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_consumer_properties